# Retrieve vendor specific information from WiFi in Android

Tags: android, wifi

Does anybody know how to retrieve the vendor information of the WiFi networks detected in Android??  For instance, if it is a Cisco router, there seems to be some way to determine this from the phone.

There seems to be a number of applications that can do it.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=list.name&hl=en

These do not seem to be present in the ScanResult received.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably use a MAC address database to look up the vendor.

I couldn't find a Java library for it, but Wireshark maintains a database: https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf

You would have to import it into your application, maybe in your SQLite database and use that as the lookup.

Comment: Sounds like a good start, my head was in so many different places I wasn't even thinking it was MAC translation.  Thanks.  I will leave this open just in case anyone has more input and mark your answer as the one if not.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. It's an interesting topic :) I've released an app on Android related to WiFi network detection. If you look up my profile you can check it out.